# Sig figs and exact numbers

Tags: arithmetic

I have a question about sig figs and decimals. If you start off with an exact value like 8.00 m which is 3 sig fig and you multiply by 100 cm so 800 cm. Then you divide by 2.54 cm and get 314.96 in. Because it's 3 sig fig you round to get 315 inch my question is do you still place a decimal to get 315. Inch Or is it just 315 inch with no decimal. I am confused because by dividing by 2.54 cm and rounding it's no longer exact right? But you started off with an exact value of 8.00 m so does that make 315. Inch ?

Any pointers will help. Thanks.

Comment: As I recall the extra decimal at the end is just to distinguish when a tail of zeros $0$ at the end of an integer are significant or not. That is, in 100, you have one significant digit, while in 100. you have three. Scientific notation removes this issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are muddling up the difference between an exact value and a measurement.

$8.00$ is not an exact value unless it is a constant from a formula. If you got the value of $8.00$ from an experiment it means that you measured $8.00\pm0.005$ and it is not exactly the same as the integer $8$.

Similarly was the value $100$ from a formula (converting to a percentage maybe) or a measurement? And was $2.54$ a measurement or from a formula? If its the conversion from centimetres to inches then its a precise constant and has no error.

If the final value of $314.96$ resulted from some measurement in the calculation stesp then yes should have the answer of $315$ which is meaning $315\pm0.05$. You sound worried that people may think that it is an exact value as it has no decimal point. The fact it is a calculated value should be apparent from the words you use around it. If there is doubt you could write it as $315\pm0.5$ or as $3.15\times10^2$ or as $(3.15\pm0.005)\times10^2$.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I am sorry I should added it's converting 8.00 m to inches

Answer (score 0):

If you start with just 8 it has infine significant figures. But 8.00 has exactly 3 significant figures. It's a common to get in chaos so we generally follow something different. Instead of writing 315 or 315. We follow 3.15 ×$10^2$ . So it has 3 significant numbers and less confusion.

## we generally write one digit before decimal(from 1 to 9) and latter according to no. Of significant numbers.

## $10^2$ doesn't count for significant digits.